# Connecting django-social-auth with a custom user model: UserSocialAuth.user must be a 'login' instance

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

I need help to connect the django-social-auth with my custom user model:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.Login'
```

So the new users will be created inside my login App. This is the error that I am getting:

```
Django Version: 1.5.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: Cannot assign "<django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x10be47090>": 
"UserSocialAuth.user" must be a "Login" instance.
```

Here is how my settings.py looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social_auth',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('facebook',)
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'xxx'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = 'xxx'

SOCIAL_AUTH_BACKEND_ERROR_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_URL = '/complete/facebook'

SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.Login'
```

And this is the login's model:

```
from django.db import models

class Login(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.username, self.email, self.creation_date)

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name_plural = "Login"
```

What am I missing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why aren't you using more recent https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth ? Also, it seems you are trying to add a linked account to existing and logged in user, correct? Have you set up Django's auth system to use your model, as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model ?